# Ruby Construct JSON Conditionally

Tags: ruby, json

I'd like to create a JSON object in ruby with attributes added conditionally

```
  step_json = {
    "id" => step.id,
    "name" => step.name,
    "position" => step.position,
    "ancestry" => step.ancestry,
    "image_path" => (step.first_image.image_path_url || step.first_image.s3_filepath) if step.first_image.present?,
    "label" => step.label if step.label.present?,
    "label_color" => step.last_color if step.label.present?
  }
```

I am getting errors for my conditional statements.  Is there a way to do this without doing if / else statements around the entire step_json object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a single entry to the object conditionally after you create the static entries.

```
step_json = {
  "id" => step.id,
  "name" => step.name,
  "position" => step.position,
  "ancestry" => step.ancestry
}
step_json['image_path'] = (step.first_image.image_path_url || step.first_image.s3_filepath) if step.first_image.present?
step_json['label'] = step.label if step.label.present?
step_json['label_color'] = step.last_color if step.label.present?
```